# CI database error find on next 4th column

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, model

I have this error :

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'condition LIKE '%Chisel Round size: 120x3/440%')' at line 3

```
SELECT * FROM `inv_tool` WHERE (insert_date LIKE '%Chisel Round size: 120x3/440%' 
          || item_group LIKE '%Chisel Round size: 120x3/440%' || 
             item_name LIKE '%Chisel Round size: 120x3/440%' || 
             serial_number LIKE '%Chisel Round size: 120x3/440%' ||
             condition LIKE '%Chisel Round size: 120x3/440%')
```

> Filename:
>   D:/*LocalWebServer*/htdocs/ptes_is/application/models/Model_invsys.php
>
> Line Number: 73

If I use this more than 3 column to find :

```
       public function find_in_tool ($find) {
            $this -> db -> where ("(insert_date LIKE '%$find%' || 
                           item_group LIKE '%$find%' || item_name LIKE '%$find%' || 
                         serial_number LIKE '%$find%' || condition LIKE '%$find%')");
            $query = $this -> db -> get ('inv_tool') ;
            return $query -> result () ;
        }
```

But if I use only 3, there is no problem.

```
       public function find_in_tool ($find) {
            $this -> db -> where ("(insert_date LIKE '%$find%' || 
                         item_group LIKE '%$find%' || item_name 
                         LIKE '%$find%')");
            $query = $this -> db -> get ('inv_tool') ;
            return $query -> result () ;
        }
```

But i really need more than 3 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has nothing to do with the number of columns, has to do with MySQL/MariaDB reserved keywords (condition): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Wrap your column names and table names in backticks to avoid conflicts:

```
`condition` LIKE ...
```

Comment: if i use backticks there is no return value. in other word, my column name didn't readable in model, last query said `SELECT * FROM `inv_tool` WHERE ('insert_date' LIKE '%cons%' || 'item_group' LIKE '%cons%' || 'item_name' LIKE '%cons%' || 'serial_number' LIKE '%cons%' || 'condition' LIKE '%cons%') ORDER BY `insert_date` DESC `

Comment: hohoho ... my bad ... is the same with tilde?

Comment: Same key as tilde on most latin keyboards, just without the shift key.